# etex.sty not found!

Tags: errors, e-tex

I copy `.tex` file from MikTeX to Scientific Word; in MikTeX, everything is fine; but in SW, I got `etex.sty not found.` error.

I copy the file `stex.sty` from MikTeX to SW; then 
I go the following error message.

```
! Package etex Error: This package may only be run using an
(etex) etex in extended mode.
```

I checked my MikTex and find the `etex` file:

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc
```

But it does not say which package the file is in? You know that means I do not know which package I need to add to SW.

Could someone help me with that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 3):

Confusingly, there are two things called `etex`: a version of TeX that has more features, and a LaTeX package that uses these two features. Obviously, you are using a package that needs the `etex` package, but this package only works with the `etex` version of TeX. As stated in the reply to [your question at the MacKichan website](http://forum.mackichan.com/node/896), Scientific Word does not support the `etex` version of TeX. This means that you cannot use whatever package that needs `etex` with Scientific Word; you will have to write this document entirely with MiKTeX, or remove that package.

Comment: the question is malformed, in fact.  there are two names: e-TeX for the extended version of TeX, and `etex.sty` for the macro package.  (doesn't impact on the value of your answer, but...)  the original question is not about failure to find `etex.sty`, but the fact that scientific word _won't run_ `etex.sty`

Comment: TeX distibutions have been using -TeX as the engine for LaTeX since at least ten years. It's rather strange that MacKichan never found the time for upgrading.