# TeX to ScientificWorkplace and back

Tags: incompatibility, conversion, scientific-workplace

I use TeXWorks while coauthors are stuck with ScientificWorkplace. They are not (even) able to save the document as `Portable LaTeX`.

Is there a "standard" preamble I could add to the .tex document to make these two compatible, such that I can read and compile the document from them, and after changes they can do the same?

E.g. even after including the tcilatex file or commenting it out, I still had issues with operators such as `\dbigcup` or `\dsum`. I was able to address those specifically, but would like a more general solution.

Comment: Which version of SWP do your coauthors use? And, what is preventing them from doing a "File -> Save As" and choosing the "Portable LaTeX" option?

Comment: I think they have 5.0 or 5.5. Not being able to do a 'Portable Latex' has to do with them being not-so-young Professors... Most people who use those sorts of programs also fail to remember that sort of thing; they just press "Save" out of habit.

Comment: I've given up working with people who use swp.  Too much hassle.

Comment: What about having the same install of SWP and do the "portable LaTeX" save yourself? (I don't know SWP)

Comment: @RomainPicot -- SWP is $$$-payware.

Comment: @Mico : in this case. I know the strugle with for example `.xlsx` file `:/`

Comment: Is anybody out there? just nod if you can hear me..

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to figure out how to train your co-authors to use `File -> Save As -> "Portable LaTeX"`. The LaTeX code produced via the "Portable LaTeX" option is actually quite decent. Separately, do ask your co-authors if they have the funds to upgrade to version 6.0 of SWP, which was released (finally!!) earlier this year, after about ten years of stagnation at version 5.5.

Comment: Since this is commercial software: Have you contacted their support?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I have the same situation.  A coauthor uses SWP.  I quickly discovered it does not support e-tex, and so many packages these days require e-tex, that there are many documents that won't compile under SWP as a result.  We gave up trying to work a format transition, and now he just red-letter edits my PDFs and I do the LaTeX formatting.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- the `e-tex` is a deal-breaker.  if it hasn't been implemented in swp yet (i don't know the answer to that), this would be an appropriate answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, zx of 2013..., http://forum.mackichan.com/node/896

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123834/etex-sty-not-found